# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ContactsController#create Couldn't find Company without an ID error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

When i try to submit at localhost:3000/companies/1/contacts/new i get the error Couldn't find Company without an ID https://gist.github.com/overhang/f8c20d2d2c851cdee7b1 any clue?
I reckon it might be a problem with routes.rb

Comment: What action are you trying to submit to? If it's `contacts#new`, you shouldn't need to submit anything – it's a `GET` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following lines from `routes.rb`

```
# config/routes.rb
# get "companies/index"

# get "companies/new"

# get "companies/show"

# get "companies/create"

# get "companies/edit"
```

Notice that RESTful controller actions like `edit` and `show` require a specific `Company` passed in order for the correct company to be looked up. These `get` routes don't allow for that. Instead, you should be utilizing the resource routes you've `already` created:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :companies
```

The non-resourceful routes are impeding the execution of the resourceful ones. Removing them should fix your problem.

Comment: Have you restarted your server?